# How to convert date type column in oracle to int type on kafka topic through JDBC connector

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to pull data from one or oracle tables to kafka topic, using JDBC connector. In my source table, there is field - test_date which is of "date" data type. sample values in this column are like -11/20/1997 12:00:00 AM.

the schema on topic of this field i am getting is of type:long -

"name": "TEST_DATE",
"type": [
"null",
{
"type": "long",
"connect.version": 1,
"connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
"logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
}

But i want to get this with type as int as below:

```
"type": [
    "null",
    {
      "type": "int",
      "connect.version": 1,
      "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Date",
      "logicalType": "date"
```

Value converted settings for me is like  -
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"

Any helps, how to achieve this?

I tried few things but its not working. one more thing is that i just want to handle one field this way and dont want to change anything on other date  fields.

Answer (score 0):

> want to get this with type as int

Unix epoch time in milliseconds should always be a long

If you want to type-cast to anything else (such as back to a string), look at using `TimestampConverter` class